# Finding paths longer than x where the sum of their weights (a property) are more than Y in cypher neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

in my neo4j graph DB I have issues and persons as my nodes, and relationships are "links" (issue to issue), and "resource" (issue to person).

I'm interested in finding all paths of issues where the sum of their weights is greater than a threshold y and the overall length of the chain is longer than x.

I'm not sure if the following works, as I think it just gives me issues with 5 links

```
MATCH (s:Issue)-[rs:links*5..]->(m:Issue)
WITH s, rs, m
unwind rs as r
return s AS source_node,
       id(s) AS source_id,
       r,
       m AS target_node,
       id(m) AS target_id
```

I've tried with count as well but I don't think it is the right way to proceed.

Comment: Hi @Stefan-Georg! Did my answer help you solve your problem? If so, can you [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark? This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, use [REDUCE()](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-reduce) to accumulate the weights of relationships. Consider a x = 5 and y = 200:

```
MATCH (s:Issue)-[rs:links*5..]->(m:Issue) // match depths with 5 (x) or more
WITH REDUCE(weights = 0, rel IN rs | weights + rel.weight) AS total_weight, s, rs, m
WHERE total_weight < 100 // filter by total_weight < y (100)
unwind rs as r
return s AS source_node,
       id(s) AS source_id,
       r,
       m AS target_node,
       id(m) AS target_id
```